# How can I run MATLAB scripts on atom?

Tags: matlab, atom-editor

I installed `script` for atom, which supports matlab code.  I also installed `language-matlab` but am still unable to run matlab code in atom.

The console returns

```
Unable to run

matlab
Did you start Atom from the command line?

  atom .
Is it in your PATH?
```

I have started from the command line.  Can someone lend me a hand?

Comment: Windows, Mac, or Linux? Open terminal/cmd and type `matlab`. What happens?

Comment: Mac.  Typing `matlab` in terminal says that `command not found`.

Comment: There is your problem. `matlab` isn't in the `PATH`. You will need to find the location that matlab was installed to and add that to your path before Atom will pick it up.

Comment: FYI, on Mac MATLAB is usually in `/Applications/MATLAB_R????x.app/bin`, where `????` is the year and `x` is either a or b.

Comment: @ChrisW So I was able to add matlab to my `PATH`, however running `matlab` from terminal still does not start matlab.  Instead, I have to use `matlab -nodesktop` to run matlab from the terminal.  Thoughts?

Comment: @DemetriP what does running `matlab` do? If the `nodesktop` flag works it is obviously being recognized in your path.